# Flutter can't use textfield properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't properly see a text written inside textfield
In addition when I reach the end of the TextField my text vanishes
I solve it by wrapping TextField in Expanded Widget it worked till today

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZyH4.jpg

```
SizedBox(
      height: device.height * 39 / 812,
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: new Border.all(color: Color.fromRGBO(49, 80, 175, 0.36)),
          color: Color.fromRGBO(249, 248, 255, 1),
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(7.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, right: 10),
              child: CheckBox(
                null,
                false,
                Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              width: 300,
              // height: 30,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your textfield with Flexible widget as follows

Flexible(
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 12.0),
      child: TextFormField (
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
     ),
    )
  )

Comment: solution: contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero